# How to calculate the accuracy of a yes/no Monte Carlo simulation such as "throwing stones in a pond"?

Tags: variance, monte-carlo, accuracy

I have a simulation that returns "yes" or "no" for each iteration, and I measure the average number of "hits" over many iterations to estimate the likelihood of "yes" occurring.  I'd like to be able to say how accurate/trustworthy that estimate of the likelihood is, though.

[Monte Carlo integration](https://web.northeastern.edu/afeiguin/phys5870/phys5870/node69.html) explains a similar basic Monte Carlo simulation:

> Imagine that we want to measure the area of a pond with arbitrary
> shape. Suppose that this pond is in the middle of a field with known
> area $A$. If we throw $N$ stones randomly, such that they land within
> the boundaries of the field, and we count the number of stones that
> fall in the pond $N_{in}$, the area of the pond will be approximately
> proportional to the fraction of stones that make a splash, multiplied
> by $A$:
>
> $$A_{pond}=\frac{N_{in}}{N}A.$$

That page then talks about a similar scenario, where you do integration of a function by [checking whether random points are under it or not](https://web.northeastern.edu/afeiguin/phys5870/phys5870/node70.html):

> imagine a rectangle of height $H$ in the integration interval $[a,b]$, such that the function $f(x)$ is within its boundaries. … The fraction of points that fall within the area contained below $f(x)$ … is an estimate of the ratio of the integral of $f(x)$ and the area of the rectangle.

But then it switches to a *different* method of integration, where instead of checking yes/no for whether your test points falls under the curve, you instead evaluate the curve itself:

> Another Monte Carlo procedure is based on the definition:
> $$\langle g \rangle=\frac{1}{(b-a)} \int_a^b{f(x)dx}.$$
>
> In order to determine this average, we sample the value of $f(x)$:
>
> $$\langle f \rangle \simeq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(x_i),$$

And then it tells how to calculate the variance for *that* type of method:

> A possible measure of the error is the "variance" $\sigma^2$ defined by:
> $$\sigma ^2=\langle f^2 \rangle - \langle f \rangle ^2, $$

But I don't understand how to take this variance calculation and transfer it back to the original "number of hits" type of calculation.  I'm not sure what function $f$ I'm evaluating or how to evaluate it.

Comment: I am unable to match your description to the page you link to.  Regardless, this is a Bernoulli experiment and the errors are exactly described by Binomial distributions.  You can read a huge amount about this situation on our site.  With [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+monte+carlo+variance+binomial+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2) I found some details at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151163: would this answer your question?

Comment: @whuber No, I don't understand that question or how it applies to mine. :/

Comment: @whuber This result from your search seems applicable though https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71228/11633

Comment: That's exactly the same answer, but with a more direct focus on the estimation variance.

Comment: @whuber Well I've read both of those links carefully and I still don't know the answer to my question.  Both seem to be about "How many trials do I need to do to reach a specific variance?", while I would like to know "How can I calculate the variance of my estimate after I've done N trials?"  If I've done N trials and M of them are "yes", then I can say that the probability of "yes" is M/N, but how accurate is that estimate?

Comment: *Both* answers contain explicit calculations of that variance.

Comment: @whuber Do you mean $$\widehat{\text{Var}}(\hat\theta) = \frac{\hat\theta(A-\hat\theta)}{n}$$? So for the pond example, the *estimated* variance would be $$\frac{N_{in}(A-N_{in})}{N}$$?

Comment: That's incorrect: $A$ is an *area* while the $N_{in}$ and $N$ are *counts:* you can hardly subtract a count from an area!  The estimator of the area is $\hat\theta = AN_{in}/N,$ which does make sense as a fraction of an area.

Comment: @whuber Ah, I misinterpreted the text. Good point about incompatible units.  *OK*...  Let me try once more: "The *estimated* variance of the *estimated* area $\widehat{A_{pond}}$ is given by 

$$\widehat{\operatorname{Var}}(\widehat{A_\mathrm{pond}}) = \frac{\frac{N_\mathrm{in}}{N}A(A - \frac{N_\mathrm{in}}{N}A)}{N}=\frac{N_\mathrm{in}A^2(1-\frac{N_\mathrm{in}}{N})}{N^2}$$

Do I finally get it?

Comment: That looks correct.  In fact, a suggestive way to write your formula is the form $$A^2\left(\frac{N_{in}}{N}\right)\left(1 - \frac{N_{in}}{N}\right)/N$$ because the factors have clear interpretations: $A^2$ arises by using the base area $A$ as the unit of measurement; $1/N$ arises in the usual way from an average of $N$ independent observations; and the rest has the familiar form $(\hat p)(1-\hat p)$ for the variance of a Bernoulli$(\hat p)$ variable.  In short, this is the usual formula for the (squared) *standard error* of an estimate of $\theta$ for Binomial sampling.

Comment: Turns out I already asked this https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/430409/11633  Too bad I can't post the correct answer here now that I finally understand it.  :/ https://gist.github.com/endolith/9e73ea30511f0befb9b336526f34d0a6